# Prevent app icons from being added automatically to home screen on a Motorola device running Android 11

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, android-11, motorola

I am running stock Android 11 on a Motorola device. I am trying to disable the feature that adds newly installed apps to my home screen.

I read an article [How to stop new apps from being added to your home screen on Android Oreo](https://9to5google.com/2017/10/29/how-to-stop-new-apps-from-being-added-to-your-home-screen-on-android-oreo/) that says

> #### How to stop new apps from being added to your home screen on Android Oreo |
>
> 1. Navigate to your Android device’s home screen
> 2. Locate a blank section of the display and long press on it
> 3. Three options will appear. Tap on **Home Settings**
> 4. Toggle the switch off (so that it’s grayed out) next to **Add Icon to Home screen**

but the switch to "Add icon to home screen" is missing.

[image]

Can somebody help me disable the feature?

Comment: I think it also depends on the launcher apps, whether they add this setting or not, so you might want to check if the setting is still available on the Play Store instead.

Comment: @AndrewT. Sorry for late reply, I couldn't manage to find any such option in Play Store; However, when I searched for the same in my settings apps, I saw that option but when I clicked it, it redirected me to the same page with no such option. I think it is probably a bug? Anyways can I forcefully change it by modifying system files?

Answer (score 2):

Instructions are missing a step - added below

1. Navigate to your Android device’s home screen
2. Locate a blank section of the display and long press on it
3. Three options will appear. Tap on Home Settings
4. Tap Home Screen Style, then the settings cog next to App Tray
5. Toggle off "Add app icons to the Home screen"